# update attributes of child elements after jQuery clone function

Tags: jquery, clone, attr

I had some code that seemed to work ok with older versions of jQuery, up until 1.4 I think.  I noticed it stopped working for sure with 1.4.4.  And still doesn't work with 1.6.2.  I did some research and there are some similar questions on this issue, but I haven't found a scenario where something more than just the id has to be updated after doing a clone().

Does anyone know how I can re-write this so it'll work with the current version of jQuery?

```
 //Add dynamic Shot handling
$('#link_addShot').click(function() {
  var cloned = $('#tbl_shots tbody tr:last').clone(true);
  prevNum = numOfShots;
        numOfShots = numOfShots + 1;
  $('#shot_number_' + prevNum, cloned).attr('name', 'shot_number_' +  numOfShots);
        $('#shot_type_id_' + prevNum, cloned).attr('name', 'shot_type_id_' +  numOfShots);
        $('#player_id_' + prevNum, cloned).attr('name', 'player_id_' +  numOfShots);

        $('#shot_number_' + prevNum, cloned).attr('id', 'shot_number_' +  numOfShots);
        $('#shot_type_id_' + prevNum, cloned).attr('id', 'shot_type_id_' +  numOfShots);
        $('#player_id_' + prevNum, cloned).attr('id', 'player_id_' +  numOfShots);
  $('#removeLink', cloned).html('<a href="#">Remove</a>');
  $('#removeLink a', cloned).click(function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().remove();
    return false;
  })

  $('#shot_type_id_' + numOfShots, cloned).val(0);
        $('#player_id_' + numOfShots, cloned).val(0);

  $('#tbl_shots').append(cloned);
  $(this).removeClass('form_button_hover');
  return false;     
});

    //remove link handling
    $(".link_remove").click(function() {
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().remove();
        return false;
    });
```

Oh, it'll probably help if I include the tr markup I'm trying to clone:

```
<tr>
<td><input id="shot_number_5" type="hidden" value="" name="shot_number_5">
<select id="shot_type_id_5" class="shot_type_id" name="shot_type_id_5">
  <option value="0">Unknown</option>
  <option value="1">Tee</option>
  <option value="2">Fairway</option>
  <option value="3">Rough</option>
  <option value="4">Bunker (fairway)</option>
  <option value="8">Bunker (greenside)</option>
  <option value="5">Fringe</option>
  <option selected="selected" value="6">Green</option>
  <option value="7">Penalty</option>
  <option value="9">Concede</option>
  <option value="10">Pick Up</option>
</select></td>
<td class="td_last" align="center"><div id="removeLink"> <a class="link_remove" href="">Remove</a> </div></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  I'm glad you were able to figuere out your problem.  The best for people to know that the problem is fixed would be to put the information from your last edit as an asnwer to your own question, then accept it as the answer.  Happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

Ok, if anyone else is looking for something similar, found a solution. I think it was both a logic issue and a syntax issue. But not sure if I really needed to change the syntax or not. The logic issue was the prevNum was actually incorrect, so instead I changed it to use a find() function with a wildcard after the ID, cause I know there is only one of those within the cloned element.

```
//Add dynamic Shot handling
$('#link_addShot').click(function() {
numOfShots = numOfShots + 1;
var cloned = $('#tbl_shots tbody tr:last').clone(true);
cloned.find('#[id*=shot_number_]').attr('id', 'shot_number_' +  numOfShots).attr('name','shot_number_' +  numOfShots);
cloned.find('#[id*=shot_type_id_]').attr('id', 'shot_type_id_' +  numOfShots).attr('name','shot_type_id_' +  numOfShots).val(0);            
cloned.find('#[id*=player_id_]').attr('id', 'player_id_' +  numOfShots).attr('name','player_id_' +  numOfShots).val(0);
cloned.find('.removeLink').html('<a href="#">Remove</a>');
cloned.find('.removeLink a').click(function() {
$(this).parent().parent().parent().remove();
return false;
});

$('#tbl_shots').append(cloned);

$(this).removeClass('form_button_hover');
return false;     
});
```